# no puedo guardar el mismo nombre de la imagen en el objeto y en el backend en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, angular, fileupload

Tengo un backend en nodejs con express que guarda los nombres de las imagenes asi ksjdfkjsdk_sdjkf.png pero mi codigo me graba el nombre y la extension de la imagen con el nombre que tiene la imagen en el disco duro por ejemplo "indice.png" y a la hora de mostrar las imagenes con angular logicamente no me las muestra por que el nombre es diferente.

No se que modificar para que en el objeto libro se guarde el mismo nombre de la imagen en el objeto que en el backend con nodejs...

create.component.html

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-2 col-form-label"
  >Imagen</label>
  <input
  style="display: none"
  
  formControlName="image"
  type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)"
  #fileInput>
<button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
</div>


  onFileChanged(event)
  {

    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    //this.selectedFile = this.book.image;
    console.log(this.selectedFile);
  }


this.book = this.forma.value;
      const uploadData = new FormData();


      uploadData.append('myFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);

      this.http.post('http://localhost:3999/admin/save', uploadData)
        .subscribe(
          response =>
          {
            this.forma.reset();
            this.userservice.create(this.book).subscribe(
              response =>
              {
                console.log(this.book);
                this.snackBar.open('book created', 'Close',{duration:3000});
             },
            error =>
            {
            console.log(error);
            }
            );
          }
        );
    }

  }
```

backend con nodejs

```
save: function(req, res){
        // Recoger los parametros de la petición
        var params = req.body;

        // Validar los datos
        try{
            var validate_title = !validator.isEmpty(params.title);
            var validate_description = !validator.isEmpty(params.description);
            var validate_author= !validator.isEmpty(params.author);
            var validate_price = !validator.isEmpty(params.price);
      var validate_stock = !validator.isEmpty(params.stock);
            //console.log(validate_name, validate_surname, validate_email, validate_password);
        }catch(err){
            return res.status(200).send({
                                message: "Faltan datos por enviar del libro"
                            });
        }

        if(validate_title && validate_description && validate_author && validate_price && validate_stock){
            // Crear objeto de usuario
            var book = new Book();

            // Recoger el fichero de la petición
            var file_name = 'Avatar no subido...';

            if(!req.files){
                return res.status(404).send({
                        status: 'error',
                        message: file_name
                });
            }

            // Conseguir el nombre y la extension del archivo
        //  var file_path = params.image;
      var file_path = req.files.file0.path;
        //  var file_split = file_path.split('\\');

            // ** Adventencia ** En linux o mac
            var file_split = file_path.split('/');

            // Nombre del archivo
            var file_name = file_split[2];

            // Extensión del archivo
            var ext_split = file_name.split('\.');
            var file_ext = ext_split[1];

            // Comprobar extension (solo imagenes), si no es valida borrar fichero subido
            if(file_ext != 'png' && file_ext != 'jpg' && file_ext != 'jpeg' && file_ext != 'gif'){
                fs.unlink(file_path, (err) => {

                    return res.status(200).send({
                        status: 'error',
                        message: 'La extensión del archivo no es valida.'
                    });

                });

            }

            // Asignar valores al objeto
            book.title = params.title;
            book.description = params.description;
            book.author = params.author;
            book.price = params.price;
            book.image = file_name;
      book.stock = params.stock;


            // Comprobar si el usuario existe
            Book.findOne({title: book.title}, (err, issetBook) => {
                if(err){
                    return res.status(500).send({
                        message: "Error al comprobar duplicidad del libro"
                    });
                }

                if(!issetBook){


                        //y guardar libro
                        book.save((err, bookStored) => {
                            if(err){
                                return res.status(500).send({
                                    message: "Error al guardar el libro"
                                });
                            }

                            if(!bookStored){
                                return res.status(400).send({
                                    message: "El libro no se ha guardado"
                                });
                            }

                            // Devolver respuesta
                            return res.status(200).send({
                                status: 'success',
                                user: bookStored
                            });

                        }); // close save


                }else{
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        message: "El libro ya está registrado"
                    });
                }

            });


        }else{
            return res.status(200).send({
                message: "Validación de los datos del libro incorrecta, intentalo de nuevo"
            });
        }

    },
```